# Check if method exists in the same class

Tags: php, class, methods, exists

So, `method_exists()` requires an object to see if a method exists. But I want to know if a method exists from within the same class.

I have a method that process some info and can receive an action, that runs a method to further process that info. I want to check if the method exists before calling it. How can I achieve it?

Example:

```
class Foo{
    public function bar($info, $action = null){
        //Process Info
        $this->$action();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answers below are fine, just an additional remark: did you ask yourself _why_ you need to find out if the method exists? This situation _may_ arise if you have a method inherited from a parent class or if you are unsure about what the current class inherits from. Both cases can be dealt with by using an interface or an abstract method definition. Which is more transparent and moves the error from runtime to compile time, thus is preferable.

Comment: Because I have some other methods that are public and further process that information and return the processed data, the first method does not return, because it can receive data that just have to be processed and doesn't need to return anything. But I thought it would be time saver to call the other method from the fisrt method if needed, but still be able to call them separatelly.

Comment: But inside the class itself, why should it be unclear if a method exists? I mean either it _is_ declared/implemented in the class or it is not. How and why should that change at runtime? I'd say you know exactly if the method exist.

Comment: Because `$action` can receive a method name that does not exists.

Comment: Ah, you specify a method by handing over its name as a string. Indeed, very ugly and insecure...

Comment: All other methods in this class are public and related to that first method. But tell me, why do you think it's ugly and insecure?

Comment: It is ugly, since you violate the idea behind OOP. You try to control from the outside scope what is happening inside the object, whilst the main goal of OOP is to _hide_ all internals of objects to the outside scope so that the internals can be changed without impact.

Comment: But all the others methods are public, and at least one of them is needed most of the times to return something. So I don't see why it's ugly to have an option to automatically run one of them, since most of the times I don't need to call them separatelly(there are times I need to call them separatelly, otherwise they would be private, or implemented in the same method)

Comment: And back to the insecure, why do you think it's insecure?

Comment: Well, you reference a function by specifying its name in a runtime argument. This is your current issue, you are currently looking for a way to protect you from this issue. So you yourself already realized it is insecure. Sure, you can probably get this secured, but wouldn't it make more sense to solve the issue itself instead of trying to cure a symptom?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class A{
    public function foo(){
        echo "foo";
    }

    public function bar(){
        if(method_exists($this, 'foo')){
            echo "method exists";
        }else{
            echo "method does not exist";
        }
    }
}

$obj = new A;
$obj->bar();
```

Answer (score 11):

Using `method_exists` is correct.  However if you want to conform to the "Interface Segregation Principle", you will create an interface to perform introspection against, like so:

```
class A
{
    public function doA()
    {
        if ($this instanceof X) {
            $this->doX();
        }

        // statement
    }
}

interface X
{
    public function doX();
}

class B extends A implements X
{
    public function doX()
    {
        // statement
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->doA();
// Does A::doA() only

$b = new B();
$b->doA();
// Does B::doX(), then remainder of A::doA()
```

Comment: @Rafael Don't you just love OOP.

Comment: I was starting to, but you killed it @Flosculus

Comment: i just knew that PHP has an interface and you can implement it. thought we can do that only in java lol. thanks dude

Comment: That won't help if A extends B and you have no control of B (it is provided by 3rd party)

Answer (score 6):

`method_exists()` accepts either a class name or object instance as a parameter. So you could check against `$this`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

> **Parameters** ¶
>
> *object* 
>   An object instance or a class name
>
> *method_name* 
>   The method name

Comment: I think you gave me a link to the manual to support what you said, but in the manual it says it needs an OBJECT. I'll try what you said, back in a moment...

Comment: highlighting the interesting part above for you

Comment: Ow, (face in the ground), sorry =p

Answer (score 5):

The best way in my opinion is to use __call magic method.

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    throw new Exception("Method {$name} is not supported.");
}
```

Yes, you can use method_exists($this ...) but this is the internal PHP way.