# how to echo something if called method doesnt exists in class

Tags: php, class, methods

Im trying to echo "sorry i dont know what to do" if we call a method that doesnt exist in my class (named Pony)

Here is my Class :

```
<?php

class Pony{
    public $_name;
    public $_gender;
    public $_color;

    public function __construct($name,$gender,$color)
    {
          $this->_name=$name;
          $this->_gender=$gender;
          $this->_color=$color;
    }


    public function speak(){
        echo "Hiii hiii hiiii<br>";
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo "I'm a dead pony.<br>";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return "Don't worry, im a pony ! <br>";
    }
}
```

but when i try to write my "if statement" inside my class, the method_exists function just doesnt take the name of my class in parameter..

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Im trying to echo "sorry i dont know what to do" if we call a method that doesn't exist inside my class Pony

Comment: can you add the if statement in this post?

Comment: I rollbacked your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if method exists in the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938206/check-if-method-exists-in-the-same-class)

Comment: Use it like this: [`method_exists($this, 'foo')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33938381/1767412)

Answer (score 1):

When calling non_existing method of class, method `__call` is invoked:

```
class Pony{
    public $_name;
    public $_gender;
    public $_color;

    public function __construct($name,$gender,$color)
    {
          $this->_name=$name;
          $this->_gender=$gender;
          $this->_color=$color;
    }


    public function speak(){
        echo "Hiii hiii hiiii<br>";
    }
    public function __destruct()
    {
        echo "I'm a dead pony.<br>";
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return "Don't worry, im a pony ! <br>";
    }

    public function __call($methodName, $arguments)
    {
        return "im a pony, i don't know what to do with {$methodName}! <br>";
    }

}

$p = new Pony('', '', '');
echo $p->swim();
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/1dsIG).